# threejs fixed view for all the models

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-canvas

am using threejs to view the 3D models, it is working fine in the way, however am using 2 different models for the example work around,

Here is the example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - loaders - OBJ loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }

            #Viewer {
                position: absolute;

                width: -webkit-calc(100% - 310px); /* Safari */
                width: calc(100% - 310px);
                height: 100%;
                border: 0px;
            }

              .control {
                position:absolute;
                margin-left:12px;
                width:100%;
                font-weight:bold;
            }

            .controlValue {
                position:absolute;
                left:36%;
                top:0%;
            }
             #controls {
                position:absolute;
                width:250px;
                bottom:0%;
                right:0%;
                height:134px;
                background-color:White;
                opacity:.9;
                font: 13px/1.231 "Lucida Grande", Lucida, Verdana, sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="obj">
    <div id="Viewer" style="width:300px;height:300px"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="controls">
            <div class="control" id="scenes_control">
                Model
                <select class="controlValue" id="scenes_list" size="1" onchange="selectScene();" ondblclick="selectScene();">
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="control" id="cameras_control">
                Camera
                <select class="controlValue" id="cameras_list" size="1" onchange="selectCamera();" ondblclick="selectCamera();">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="control" id="animations_control">
                Animations
                <div class="controlValue"><input type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleAnimations();">Play</input></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control" id="buffer_geometry_control">
                Geometry
                <div class="controlValue">
                <input type="checkbox" id="buffer_geometry_checkbox" checked onclick="toggleBufferGeometry();">BufferGeometry</input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - OBJLoader test
        </div>

        <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../src/core/clock.js"></script>
         <script src="../src/core/Geometry.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>


        <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controls/FirstPersonControls.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            var clock = new THREE.Clock();
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

            init();
            animate();


            function init() {

                container =  document.getElementById('Viewer');
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                //camera.position.set( 2, 2, 3 );

                //camera.position.z = 100;
                camera.position.z = 40;
                camera.position.y = 700;
                // scene


                 // set the camera's behaviour and sensitivity
                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, container );
                controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
                controls.zoomSpeed = 5;
                controls.panSpeed = 2;
                controls.noZoom = false;
                controls.noPan = false;
                controls.staticMoving = true;
                controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;


                //camera.position.set( 0, 25, 0 );

                //first person
            /*  controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls( camera );

                controls.movementSpeed = 70;
                controls.lookSpeed = 0.04;
                controls.noFly = true;
                controls.lookVertical = false;*/




                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
                scene.add( ambient );

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
                scene.add( directionalLight );


                scene.add (new THREE.Mesh (geometry,
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ({ color: 0x00ffff, wireframe: true })));


            var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
                loader.load( 'files/cessna.obj', 'files/cessna.mtl', function ( object ) {


                    scene.add( object );

                } );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                var delta = clock.getDelta(),
                    time = clock.getElapsedTime() * 5;

                controls.update( delta );

                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

i can view the model on the center of the viewer, if i load another model it is not showing on the center of the viewer, instead of it showing on the top of the viewer so i can't see the full model on load of the viewer , so my controls are not working perfectly

So here how can i set the fixed position for all the models on the center of the viewer ??

Comment: Could you put it in a fiddle with the models?

Comment: anybody have the answer ??